# Toggle between HTML pages using flipswitch

Tags: javascript, html, eclipse

I have two separate html pages that I wish to toggle using a flip-switch.

The switch is "Off" by default and shows the current html page, `index.html`. When the user flips it to "On", I want to redirect them to `nextpage.html`. Similarly, if the user flips it "Off", they are redirected to `index.html`. I tried to experiment by including `onclick="index.html"` within the codes but it does not work.

Do I need a function to achieve this?

[image]

Flipswitch

```
<div class= "switch">
   <label for="title"><b>Switch to redirect:</b>
   <input type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" name="switch" id="switch"></label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since its a checkbox you can addEventListener `onchange` :

*HTML: (index.html)*

```
<div class= "switch">
 <label for="title"><b>Switch to redirect:</b>
   <input type="checkbox" data-role="flipswitch" name="switch" id="switch">
 </label>
</div>
```

*HTML: (nextpage.html)*

```
<div class= "switch">
 <label for="title"><b>Switch to redirect:</b>
   <input type="checkbox" checked="checked" data-role="flipswitch" name="switch" id="switch">
 </label>
</div>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
document.getElementById('switch').onchange = function(){
  if(this.checked){
   window.location='nextpage.html';
  } else {
   window.location='index.html';
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi Faouzi, I tried your codes but nothing happens when I flip the switch

Comment: I jus re-tested the code and working just fine, can you check console for errors?

Answer (score 0):

Use this as your onclick:

```
onclick="window.location='index.html'"
```